# How to set DD-WRT to use different DNS for 5GHz and 2,4GHz networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dd-wrt

I want the 5GHz network to use my Pi-hole DNS and the 2,4GHz network to use a different DNS.

The only place where I find DNS is in Setup -> Basic setup -> Network setup. I do not see DNS in Wireless settings.

How can I configure a different DNS for each wlan?

DD-WRT is version v3.0-r33675M kongac (11/03/17).

Comment: I do not think this is possible without setting up a separate VLAN/subnet that has a different DHCP server (which could then be used to assign a different DNS server). I believe DD-WRT has this capability, and you would probably have to broadcast a separate SSID for this segmented network setup.

Comment: This will require re-engineering your network as by default the bands are bridged together, meaning that ethernet  2.4g and 5g all look the same at the IP level (ie to dhcp/dns).  While I disagree that a different dhcp server is needed, I agree that vlans + different subnets are likely needed, alongside changes to how dhcp is deployed - in other words doing this is quite complex with changes to lots of moving parts